# C# collapsible listview WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone tell me how to achieve something like this in WPF:
[image: img]

Is this listview or gridview or maybe something else?
I'm noob at C# so thanks for any help.

Comment: Have a look at [Expander](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This is called an Expander.  You can use it like this:

```
<Expander Header="More Options">
    <StackPanel Margin="10,4,0,0">
        <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 1" />
        <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 2" />
        <CheckBox Margin="4" Content="Option 3" />
    </StackPanel>
</Expander>
```

See [this](http://wpftutorial.net/Expander.html) for more info.

To answer the question in your comment, search on [wpf listview example expander](https://www.google.com/search?q=wpf+listview+example+expander) and check out the Images and the Web results to best *inspire* on what you want to do in your app.  Plenty of examples will show you how to create object and bind them to the list/collection and show in a ListView/GridView possibly with grouping.

Comment: Great! That's what i was looking for... One more question, how to do nested listview like on the picture?